# Adding addFooterView to Listview in Activity leads null pointer exception

Tags: android, android-activity, android-listview

Hello I'm using ASYNC task to parse data from json and listing it in to an activity. However it works fine without the addFooterView. When I try to add it, it gives me null pointer exception.

```
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 
new FilesTask(baseurl, true).execute(); 
        footerView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.listview_footer, null); }

@Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            if (isLoading){
                this.cancel(true);
            } else {
                isLoading = true;
            }
            if (initialload){
                pDialog = (RelativeLayout) ll.findViewById(R.id.progressBarHolder);

                if (pDialog.getVisibility() == View.GONE) {
                    pDialog.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    feedListView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }

                if (null != feedList){
                    feedList.clear();
                }
                if (null != feedListView){
                    feedListView.setAdapter(null);
                }
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
                    feedListView.addFooterView(footerView);
                }
            } else {
                feedListView.addFooterView(footerView);
            }
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            if (null != feedList) {
                //set adapter
                updateList(initialload);

                if (pDialog.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) {
                    pDialog.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                   feedListView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                   //    Helper.revealView(feedListView,ll);
                    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
                        feedListView.addFooterView(footerView);
                    }
                } else if(footerView.getVisibility()== View.VISIBLE) {
                    feedListView.addFooterView(footerView);
                }

            }else{                                      // else feedList is empty

                pDialog.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }

            isLoading = false;
        }
```

**For reference**

```
public void updateList(boolean initialload) {
        if (initialload){
            feedListAdapter = new CustomListAdapter(getApplicationContext(), 0, feedList);
            feedListView.setAdapter(feedListAdapter);
        } else {
            feedListAdapter.addAll(feedList);
            feedListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }
```

Here I have pasted the onPreExecute and postexecute. Please advice me if I do anything wrong here. Error occures at

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
                        feedListView.addFooterView(footerView);
                    }



931-931/com.example E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example/com.example.search.SearchActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2180)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at com.example.search.SearchActivity$DownloadFilesTask.onPreExecute(SearchActivity.java:198)
            at android.os.AsyncTask.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.java:586)
            at android.os.AsyncTask.execute(AsyncTask.java:534)
            at com.example.search.SearchActivity.onCreate(SearchActivity.java:105)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: where is your `footerView` initialized

Comment: @A.S. public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 
footerView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.listview_footer, null); }

Comment: Your footerView is probably null, can you show more about its instanciation ?

Comment: @Bubu it works fine without footer, below SDK KITKAT. Above SDK Kitkat it works fine with footer. public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) { super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); footerView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.listview_footer, null); }

Comment: Can you try to add your footer BEFORE to set the adapter pls ?

Comment: @Bubu same result, no improvement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here I have to initialize listView before addFooterView.

First initialize

```
footerView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.listview_footer, null);
```

then

```
new FilesTask(baseurl, true).execute();
```

FilesTask(baseurl, true).execute(); will execute the remaining part of set adapter.
Actually This kind of error occurs SDK below KITKAT. solution is 
1. TO initialize listview,footerView 
2.Do the remaining ASNYC Task

Answer (score 0):

ListView add FootView or HeadView must before setAdapter,see the source code below.

```
 /**
 * Add a fixed view to appear at the bottom of the list. If addFooterView is called more
 * than once, the views will appear in the order they were added. Views added using
 * this call can take focus if they want.
 * <p>NOTE: Call this before calling setAdapter. This is so ListView can wrap the supplied
 * cursor with one that will also account for header and footer views.
 *
 *
 * @param v The view to add.
 */
public void addFooterView(View v) {
    addFooterView(v, null, true);
}
```

Comment: post exception log  pls.

Comment: check it now added logcat